# Insert command works in MS with Oracle Linked Server but not in Visual Basic 6

Tags: sql-server, oracle, image, vb6, linked-server

When I run a SQL insert command that gets an image and other data from a table in a Oracle Linked Server, inserting it in a SQL-Server, it works. When I run the exact same query inside a Visual Basic 6 program, the insert also works but the image isn't inserted.

The linked server part is working, as I can make several queries with success.

The insert I'm running is the one below. Notice that in both scenarios, the insert doesn't throw an error; they work in VB and Management Studio, BUT, when running through VB, just the image doesn't come.

```
INSERT INTO Employees
 (
   PhotoEmployee,
   TheID,
   Name
 )
 VALUES
 (
   (Select FOTO_Humanus From OPENQUERY(ORACLE_LinkedServer, 'Select FOTO.pesFoto FOTO_Humanus FROM Pessoa_Foto1 FOTO WHERE FOTO.pesCodPessoa = 32892')),
   '900397',
   'MARCELO ROCHA'
 )
```

I've searched a lot but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

The SQL-Server field that is receiving the image is from the IMAGE type.

In Oracle, the image is stored in a field that is from the type LONG RAW.

Can you help?

EDIT: (added more details)

The connection is ok... im pretty sure of that. Also, there is no error when I execute the SQL command or connecto to the database: Everythings works fine except for this image.. that doesnt get inserted in the destination database. All ohter fields are inserted without problems. All fields are in the same table.

The Visual Basic 6 code that i'm using is the following.

1 - O populate an array with the exact query I need

2 - Soon later I iterate in this array, executing the SQL query.

Here is the VB code:

```
SQLOracleTemp = "Select FOTO.pesFoto FOTO_Humanus FROM Pessoa_Foto1 FOTO WHERE FOTO.pesCodPessoa = 32892"

NomeLinkedServer = "ORACLE_LinkedServer"

SQL_InsertColab = "INSERT INTO Employees" & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & " (" & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   funFotoColaborador," & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   TheID," & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   Name" & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & " )" & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & " VALUES" & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & " (" & vbCrLf


SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   (Select FOTO_Humanus From OPENQUERY(" & NomeLinkedServer & ", '" & SQLOracleTemp & "'))," & vbCrLf

SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   " & aColabs_Insert(UBound(aColabs_Insert)).IDOAS & "," & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & "   " & aColabs_Insert(UBound(aColabs_Insert)).Nome & vbCrLf
SQL_InsertColab = SQL_InsertColab & " )" & vbCrLf

aSQL(UBound(aSQL)) = SQL_InsertColab
ReDim Preserve aSQL(UBound(aSQL) + 1)



For ContaSQL = 0 To UBound(aSQL)

    if aSQL(ContaSQL) <> "" then
        gConexao_Banco.Execute aSQL(ContaSQL)
    enf if

Next
```

Comment: Please show us the VB6 code which is failing

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. I've edited the question and added the VB code. The VB code creates the exact query i posted in the begining of the question. If i stop VB, get the query in debug mode and run byb hand in Management Studio.. it works. If I let the vb run.. he executes the query, the insert works... BUT .. the IMAGE doesn't came. When I check, the image field is NULL. When i do it by hand.. when i check.. i can see the image data in the field and it also appears in my application

Comment: What mode are you opening your connection with? Have you checked the connection Errors collection after calling Execute?

Comment: Hi Jac, Im using OLEDB to connect to the SQL-Server. There are no errors in the connection.. and i can run queries on it without problems

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer but I don't know how to show code formatting in comment. 
You have `ReDim Preserve aSQL(UBound(aSQL) + 1)` after `aSQL(UBound(aSQL)) = SQL_InsertColab`. Sounds strange but Probably this is correct as per your logic. Now after this you execute an array of sqlstatement in the for loop. So the last item in the array which still empty gets executed in the for loop and obviously it fails. Anyway try below. In the loop last array item doesn't execute. Check with your scenario and update it accordingly.

```
For ContaSQL = 0 To UBound(aSQL)-1
    gConexao_Banco.Errors.Clear
    gConexao_Banco.Execute aSQL(ContaSQL)
    If gConexao_Banco.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To gConexao_Banco.Errors.Count
            Debug.Print gConexao_Banco.Error(i).Number 
            Debug.Print gConexao_Banco.Error(i).Source 
            Debug.Print gConexao_Banco.Error(i).Description
        Next i
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You are correct on thinking that the last position on the array would be blank.. and probably show an error. But, in fact, I do handle that and use a ReDim Preserve aSQL(UBound(aSQL) - 1) after that point. I forgot to put it in the code.. because i made some cleaning in the code to make it simpler.. to the reader. But in the actual code.. there is a line who handle that. And, the insert is executing without problems. The problem I have is that after the successful insert... only 1 field is left with NULL : The image that I know is in the source and should be in the destination field

Comment: I didn't get, only 1 field is left with NULL. Did you mean only 1 column in the insertion gets null and rest others get inserted correctly?

Comment: Hi Makul, Exactly that! The insertion runs and the inserted record is there... BUT .... with the Photo field as null. If i run the EXACT SAME insert, but instead of running trough VB, i run it usint the Management Studio... the insert runs without errors and this time.. the image is there.

Comment: Can you please check with UBound(aColabs_Insert)-1? Also, do this value change in loop or static in the query as ubound will always be same

Comment: Hi Makul, sorry the long time to answer. This variable (aColabs_Insert) is an array of a type I created. Indeed, this whole code is iterating in a loop ... where the value in this aColabs_Insert keeps changing. But, i've checked and its fine: no errors there (I always have values in this array and the field where im facing problems doesnt came from this array). I use ubound because i've just populated this arrays with the correct data, just before the code ive posted here. I didnt post all the code to make it simpler, i hope.

Comment: Actually, I think i will solve this way: today, I'm trying to insert this image in the SQL, from Oracle, using a INSERT command, with a subquery returning the image to populate this image field (code shown in the example above). To solve it, I plan retrieving the image in a separate part of the code, probably with a different query populating a recordset or other object that can hold the data and later update it in SQL. But it keeps puzzling me: why does the insert i run directly from Management studio works and when VB runs, it works but the image doesn't came.